# Do inline embeds detract from readability and useability of a news article?

Tags: readability, news

If you have a news article, with a related gallery embedded after paragraph three, a twitter embed after a relevant paragraph referencing the Tweet, and a “for more information on x” reference link, how is the readability and useability of the text affected?

The main goal is to get people to read as much of the story as possible, on desktop and on mobile.

My gut feeling is that relevancy plays a large part, but I also feel that breaking a giant wall of text into easily digestible chunks can actually INCREASE the interaction with the story.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a related piece of information associated with a paragraph below it in a news article would always provide a better user experience as a reader would otherwise have to scroll or navigate to a different place and try to find a matching info associated to the paragraph he might have just finished reading. The latter would anyway INCREASE the interaction with the story but, at the cost of providing a good user experience.

Breaking down a large article into smaller chunks would always help in achieving better readability. Smaller paragraphs with proper associated infomation can make the user feel easy going while reading compared to that of a large body of text even if it's in paragraphs.